# SVG image size incorrect only on Android Chrome (and only recently)

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, svg

*UPDATE: I've minimized the problem to two SVG images here: https://doontoon.com/test.html. Chrome on Android is incorrectly placing the second SVG underneath. Here's a screenshot of this page loading incorrectly on the Chrome browser for Android:*
[image: test on Chrome for Android]

*It loads correctly on other browsers like this:*
[image: test on Chrome for Desktop]

---

My HTML page loads a grid of SVG squares at 50x50px.

It works everywhere I've tested (see screenshots below), except for Chrome on Android. The problem does not occur on Desktop Chrome using the Devices Toolbar in Inspector.

It **only recently** (~1mo?) stopped working on my Android Chrome browser.

- Page url: https://doontoon.com/fun.php
- Android version: 13
- Android Chrome version: 114.0.5735.130

**Relevant code beneath screenshots.**

---

Working in desktop Chrome Inspector, as it does on Brave browser for Android, (and as it used to in Android Chrome):

[image: mazes in Desktop Chrome Inspector]

Mixed up SVG images in Chrome for Android, and so page width also broken:

[image: mazes in Chrome for Android]

---

Relevant CSS:

```
:root {
    --width: 500px;
    --height: 600px;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}
#maze {
    border: 2px solid #037C73;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: var(--width);
    height: var(--height);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.rows {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Relevant SVG:

```
<svg
   width="50"
   height="50"
   viewBox="0 0 5.2916665 5.2916668"
</svg>
```

Comment: Could be a brower rendering bug. Last year I had an issue with SVG rendering in Chrome — a Chrome update caused some of my SVGs to be rendered incorrectly. I [logged a bug here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list), specifying that it was a **regression** (something which previously worked but is now broken), and they fixed the issue within a couple of weeks. Of course, if you can create a page with the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem, and link to that from your bug report, that will help immensely.

Comment: The test loaded fine on Chrome 114.0.5735.131 on Android. However, I could reproduce your problem by going to ⋮ > Settings > Accessibility and changing the "Default zoom" to 237%. I changed it back to 100%, and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment above, I cannot reproduce this anymore as of Chrome 114.0.5735.147.

I've opened a regression bug that can be followed here: [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1458657#c_ts1687982181)